# How to convert a 24 bit JPEG image into 8 bit image?

Tags: jpeg, image-editing

I have a 24-bit image. I need to convert it into an 8 bit JPEG image.  Can it be done by MS Paint or MS picture manager or I need to download any tool. I tried some tool but that did not work.

Will an 8 bit image become black and white or it remains coloured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

8bit means 2^8 colors = 256 colors, just select `Save As` on MSPaint and then `256 Colors Bitmap`. As far as converting it to `JPEG`... After saving it as 256 colors .bmp, open it and then save as `JPEG`, but I don't know what the results will be. I believe Adobe's Photoshop and GIMP (free) have the option of saving 8 bit jpegs.

It won't be black and white unless you make it black and white.

Comment: However, if you do make it black and white, it will be just as high quality as the original, just without color. A 256-color image will  be significantly degraded in quality unless the image really didn't have (much) more than 256 colors to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the image in paint
2. Click >  Save As Option <256 .bmp>
3. Open new Saved .bmp image in paint
4. Click > Save As Option < .jpeg  > as different name.